# Following example of JavaScript Promise giving error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm creating a promise which will take an input and then return (+3) to it. Then I want to print the result. Why am I getting the error?

```js
var prom = new Promise((item) => item+3);

prom(5).then(console.log(result));
```

I'm new to Promises. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you do not supply a promise with arguments. If you want to create a promise with return value, you need to create a function that returns a promise.

Second, `then` takes a function and will provide it with the result argument that you can use in your `console.log`.

```js
// var prom = new Promise((item) => item+3);
const prom = item => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(item + 3));

// prom(5).then(console.log(result));
prom(5).then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Pl, also add the initial code, where without function wrapping, you fixed and got answer. It was also helpful.

Comment: do you mean like that?

Comment: Yes, but make 2 separate examples, don't just add as comment. Let both work. Let person decide which he wants to follow.

Comment: That's a good idea, but in this case your code was giving an error, so putting it together with other code won't work, you'll see only an error and my code won't even be executed.

Answer (score 3):

You don't provide the value to the promise that way.

The only thing you get in your promise is the resolve and reject function, not the value you passed there. It is not a function, it is an object.

You can, instead, wrap it in a function like this:

```js
function prom(item) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(item+3));
}

prom(5).then(result => console.log(result));
```